# Assertion Failure in SWI-Prolog When Using pyswip to Consult a Prolog File

Tags: python, list, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm working on a project where I use pyswip to integrate SWI-Prolog with Python. As someone new to Prolog programming, I've encountered an assertion failure when attempting to consult a Prolog file using pyswip. The error occurs specifically at the prolog.consult("/mnt/data/Dynamic_aci_assignment_PS2.pl") line in my Python script. My environment uses SWI-Prolog version 9.2.2 and pyswip version 0.2.10 on a Linux system.

```
from pyswip import Prolog

prolog = Prolog()
prolog.consult("test.pl")
```

test.pl file contains -

```
% test.pl
likes(john, pizza).
```

I am getting the folllowing error -

```
/home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python /home/agaonsindhe/Desktop/codebase/python/mtech/aci/assignment_2/sample_prolog_run.py 
[Thread 1 (main) at Sun Mar 17 13:48:59 2024] ./src/pl-fli.c:2674: PL_put_chars: Assertion failed: 0
C-stack trace labeled "assert_fail":
  [0] PL_changed_cwd() at ??:? [0x75f3db6dcb3b]
  [1] _PL_atoms() at ??:? [0x75f3db6b989e]
  [2] PL_put_chars() at ??:? [0x75f3db6cbe19]
  [3] ffi_call_unix64() at :? [0x75f3dc217052]
  [4] ffi_call_int() at ffi64.c:? [0x75f3dc215925]
  [5] ffi_call() at ??:? [0x75f3dc21606e]
  [6] _call_function_pointer() at /usr/local/src/conda/python-3.11.5/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c:944 [0x75f3dbfd52e4]
  [7] PyCFuncPtr_call() at /usr/local/src/conda/python-3.11.5/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c:4201 [0x75f3dbfde4ce]
  [8] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(_PyObject_MakeTpCall+0x254) [0x502d54]
  [9] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x755) [0x50f025]
  [10] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(+0x19b8c7) [0x59b8c7]
  [11] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(+0x12bc6b) [0x52bc6b]
  [12] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(PyObject_Vectorcall+0x31) [0x51bff1]
  [13] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x755) [0x50f025]
  [14] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(+0x1c82ce) [0x5c82ce]
  [15] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCode+0x9f) [0x5c79cf]
  [16] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(+0x1e8807) [0x5e8807]
  [17] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(+0x1e4e40) [0x5e4e40]
  [18] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(+0x1f9132) [0x5f9132]
  [19] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(_PyRun_SimpleFileObject+0x19f) [0x5f871f]
  [20] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(_PyRun_AnyFileObject+0x43) [0x5f8473]
  [21] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(Py_RunMain+0x2ee) [0x5f2fee]
  [22] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(Py_BytesMain+0x39) [0x5b6e19]
  [23] __libc_start_call_main() at ./csu/../sysdeps/x86/libc-start.c:74 [0x75f3dc028150]
  [24] call_init() at ./csu/../csu/libc-start.c:128 [0x75f3dc028209]
  [25] /home/agaonsindhe/Downloads/yes/bin/python(+0x1b6c6f) [0x5b6c6f]
Prolog stack:
(null)

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6:SIGABRT)
```

What I've tried:

1. Ensuring SWI-Prolog and pyswip are properly installed and accessible in my PATH.
2. Verifying the file path and permissions for the Prolog file.
3. Running basic pyswip commands to ensure general functionality, which worked without issues.

What could be causing this assertion failure in SWI-Prolog when consulting a Prolog file via pyswip? As I am new to Prolog programming, any insights on potential fixes, workarounds, or even general advice on integrating Prolog with Python would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a prolog problem. Even without consulting external file, `prolog.assertz("likes(john, pizza)")` this is also crashing. Possibly `pyswip` bug.

Comment: Anywhere I can look into this.

Comment: I don't really use python, swi-prolog has it's own python bridge, https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/packages-swipy. Give that a try.

Comment: Maybe the issues on the pyswip on the github repo are of help. However, I suggest using the new janus interface or the package mqi, both available in SWI prolog.